# How to add a label at bottom of imageView programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to add a label at the bottom of imageView as a subview but when image changes its height or width the label is not responsive.
So i want to make a dynamic label.

[image: This is what i did until now]

Comment: are you using autolayout or else

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no i am not using autolayout, i am trying to do that programmatically by adding frame to labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here example of adding label to image

```
 let picImage:UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let image = UIImage(named: "test")
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
    }()
 let durationLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "1:20:12"
    label.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15.0)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
func setupView(){
// I will skip part of image setup
self.picImage.addSubview(durationLabel)
   durationLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: picImage.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    durationLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: picImage.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        durationLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: picImage.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
}
```

this code will add label to image that set constraint to bottom and left and right

[image]

Answer (score 2):

add like

```
 var lbl1 =  UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: yourimageview.frame.origin.x, y: yourimageview.frame.origin.y + yourimageview.frame.size.height + 5, width: yourimageview.frame.size.width, height: asyourWish))


lbl1.textColor = UIColor.black
lbl1.frame = position
lbl1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
lbl1.textColor = UIColor.white

 lbl1.text = "TEST"
self.view.addSubview(lbl1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
var label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: imageView.bounds.origin.x, y: imageView.bounds.origin.y, width: 300, height: 45)
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
label.textAlignment = .left
label.text = "This is a test label"
self.imageView.addSubview(label)
```